# JavaScript not working on contact us form

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can't close my contact us form...

There is no error found...pls suggest

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

pls check the below link
http://www.adsmania.in/

thanks in advance

Comment: why r u returning false?

Comment: @NeelBhatt — Presumably to cancel the default action of whatever `.trigger` does.

Comment: what exatly u wanna achieve?

Comment: On contact button mouse over I am getting error (lots of) `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'swing' `

Comment: There are loads of syntax errors in the Console. JS errors will stop execution and that is probably why the panel is not closing...

Comment: Yes correct @Tallmaris. And where you have written this js code in your page?

Comment: Also there is a `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"`

Comment: what do u mean by that comment @MackieeE??

Comment: The error is somewhere else not in this script, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JwPRV/2/), that is working.

Answer (score 0):

> use event.preventDefault(); to cancel the default action. Return false is used to cancel the form submission in Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".trigger").click(function(event){
     $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});